# Using xPath for sitemap.xml

Tags: php, xml, xpath, sitemap

Here is the XML file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url id="first_url">
<loc>http://example.com</loc>
<lastmod>2014-05-21</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

And here goes the PHP code:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->Load('sitemap.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);        
$tags = $xpath->query('//url[@id="first_url"]');
foreach($tags as $tag)
    print $tag->getAttribute("id")."<br/>";
?>
```

This code does not work. But if I remove `xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"` from file, it works. Why it's so? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is because of the namespace. Here is way you can do it that ignores the name space:

Xpath 1.0:

```
//*[local-name()="url"][@id="first_url"]
```

Xpath 2.0:

```
//*:url[@id="first_url"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Register the namespace using [DOMXPath::registerNamespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php)

```
$xpath->registerNamespace("s",
        "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
```

Then use it in your XPath:

```
$tags = $xpath->query('//s:url[@id="first_url"]');
```